# Better way to iterate std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Given a map, I need to retrieve and operate two immediately stored items.
To me, working on a vector is litter easier since I can do "iter + 1" or "iter - 1".
While for map, I am out of luck.

For example, I give a simple example as follows:
Note: in my real application, I don't simply subtract those numbers.

```
int main ()
{
    map<char,int> mymap;
    map<char,int>::iterator it;

    mymap['b'] = 100;
    mymap['a'] = 200;
    mymap['c'] = 300;

    // show content:
    map<char,int>::iterator firstItem  = mymap.begin();
    map<char,int>::iterator secondItem = ++mymap.begin();

    for ( ; secondItem != mymap.end(); ++firstItem, ++secondItem )
        cout << secondItem->second - firstItem->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Question> Is there a better solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Would `std::prev` and `std::next` help?

Comment: Choosing a container type depends on the generalized use cases.  If you do a lot of this type of iterating, and you don't mind paying the penalty of search performance, then using a container with random-access iterators may make sense.

Comment: @Cameron, good to know both operators but it is ONLY for C++11 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of incrementing both iterators in the loop control (incrementing is a bit slow), just assign `firstItem = secondItem` then increment `secondItem`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single iterator. Move the increment from the header to the middle of your loop, and exit the loop when you hit the end of your map, like this:

```
map<char,int>::iterator item  = mymap.begin();
for (;;) {
    int first = item->second;
    ++item;
    if ( item == mymap.end()) break;
    cout << item->second - first << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current loop will show **undefined behaviour** if the map is empty.

Your loop could be rewritten (more simply, and checking for an empty map) like so:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    map<char,int> mymap;
    map<char,int>::iterator it;

    mymap['b'] = 100;
    mymap['a'] = 200;
    mymap['c'] = 300;

    for ( it = ( mymap.begin() == mymap.end() ? mymap.end() : std::next(mymap.begin()) ) ; it != mymap.end(); ++it )
        cout << it->second - std::prev(it)->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of style. You can do eg.

```
auto first = m.begin();

if (first != m.end())
{
    auto second = first;
    second++;

    for (; second != m.end(); first = second++)
    {
        ...        
    }
}
```

You can also bailout more elegantly in the case where the map is empty. For instance you can do:

```
if (m.empty()) return;

auto first = m.begin(), second = first;

for (second++; second != m.end(); first = second++)
{
   ...
}
```

I'd favor the latter if I can, and use the former only if I must.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will have undefined behavior if the map is empty but other than that it seems to be a reasonable approach, depending on your overall goal. Since `map` iterators are not random access you can't just add or subtract one, only increment/decrement.

An alternate approach is to make a copy of the iterator and then incrementing inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Neither better, nor worse, just an alternative:

```
if (map.size() >=2)
std::accumulate(
  ++mymap.begin(),
  mymap.end(),
  mymap.begin(),
  [](mymap_type::const_iterator iprev, mymap_type::value_type const& entry)->mymap_type::const_iterator
  { 
    /* do something */;
    return ++iprev; 
  });
```